# How to plot spin texture?

Tags: vasp, vaspkit

I want to know that if there post-process tool for VASP to plot spin-texture like this? I have tried Vaspkit but it did not support my structure.
[image]

[image]

Comment: This youtube video which explains how to plot spin textures: [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Tjvy6rrRa5A)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a python library called: [pyprocar](https://github.com/romerogroup/pyprocar) to plot spin texture plots.

You can install it using pip like this : `pip install PyProcar`

Here is a sample code to plot spin textures

In the below example all the required VASP files such as PROCAR, OUTCAR etc are inside the data directory.

To perform similar plotting on your custom VASP files follow the code below and use the path of the data directory which has all your VASP files

```
import pyprocar

data_dir = pyprocar.download_example(save_dir='',
                             material='Fe',
                             code='vasp',
                             spin_calc_type='non-colinear',
                             calc_type='fermi')


pyprocar.fermi2D(code = 'vasp',
           dirname=data_dir,
           spin_texture=True,
           spin_projection='x',
           arrow_size=3,
           arrow_density=10,
           plot_color_bar=True)
```

This gives a plot like below

[image: Spin_texture]

Comment: Hi @Vandan Revanur, Thanks for your advice. I have used this code plot my data.

Comment: @TieyuanBian
If my answer has helped solve your question, please do consider it as the accepted answer by clicking on the tick mark next to the answer.